# deferred- code working with fail/done but not working with then

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I have a function called `func1` that's calling `var dfd = $.ajax`, and returning `dfd.promise()` , now in my main function, I have the code like this:

```
function addOperation() {
   var addPromise = func1();
   addPromise.then(
     function(sender, args, msg) {
       alert("success");
     },

     function() {
       alert("fail");
     });
 }
```

The above code is not working, what's working for me is:

```
function addOperation() {
  var addPromise = func1();
  addPromise.fail(
      function(sender, args, msg) {
        alert("fail");
      })
    .done(
      function() {
        alert("success");
      });
}
```

From my understanding is that then(functionSuccess, functionFail) is the same as calling .done and .fail on the original promise, isn't that right? I am lost with this.

Comment: can you provide _func1_ also?

Answer (score 1):

you should not be returning `dfd.promise()` from your function, the return value from `$.ajax` *is* the promise.

Just return `dfd` directly (or the result of `$.ajax`)

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) say it best:

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object for more information). These methods take one or more function arguments that are called when the $.ajax() request terminates

Comment: but what in this case return _dfd.promise()_?

Comment: @Grundy now, in English?

Comment: i mean, why we should not use _dfd.promise()_? what the difference between result of `$.ajax` function, and result `$.ajax(...).promise()`?

Comment: @Grundy evidently, one way works, the other does not.

Comment: :-D it would be great if you explain _why_ one way works, and the other does not.

Comment: I returned the dfd without .promise(), and used then in the calling function, but same result. Seems am using then in the wrong way

Comment: @Jamiec thanks for the docs info, but I am still not able to use then, and I don't still know what's the difference between then(successpath, failpath) vs .done.fail path.

Comment: @Natalie - then you're doing something different to you describe as this simple example works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/ya1ec7e4/ What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Jamiec, yes yes, it's working. So my understanding is that if I return the object itself (dfd), I can use then, but if am returning dfd.promise(), I should use .done and .fail, right?

Comment: @Natalie, as you can see in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ya1ec7e4/1/) your variant with returning _promise_ also work, so error some where else

Comment: Although in jQuery documentation, it says the same for .done, .fail, and .then, it says about "then": when the deferred object is resolved or reject. Check here: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ // My question is why it's working with dfd.promise() for .done and .fail, and it's not working with dfd.promise() for .then?

Comment: Both ways seem to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ya1ec7e4/2/ - but im not sure why you would *ever* do `$.ajax(...).promise()` ?!?

Comment: For me, I am resolving or rejecting the dfd in func1. Would it be the problem? Upon what you're saying, what's the use of .promise() ?

Answer (score 0):

The jqXHR object returned by `$.ajax` implements the Promise interface.

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).

Therefore, func1 should just return the value returned by `$.ajax`.